# How to derive marginal PDF from joint PDF?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We are [given that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJtoG.png) two variables $X,Y$ have the joint pdf $$f_{XY}(x,y)=x+y,\quad 0\le x\le 1,\; 0\le y\le1$$
and that the marginal pdf's are $$f_X(t)=f_Y(t)=t+\frac12$$ for $0\le t\le 1$. Could anyone shows me how it is derived ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are given the joint pdf $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=x+y, \quad \mbox{ for } 0\le x,y\le1$$ The marginal pdf's of $X,Y$ are derived as follows: \begin{align}f_X(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy&=\int_{0}^1(x+y)\;dy=\left[xy+\frac{y^2}2\right]_{0}^1=x+\frac12\end{align} for $0\le x\le 1$. By symmetry (or by a similar calculation) you get that $$f_Y(y)=y+\frac12$$ for $0\le y\le 1$. In the formula highlighted in yellow, the author calls the variables $x,y$ with $t$ to get it more neatly. This is just a matter of presentation, nothing important.